# Checking if the user wants to continue, using while and continue in Python 3.3

Tags: python, while-loop, break, continue

This is a simple program to check if a number is odd or even.I want to check if the user wants to continue or not and when I run it I get an Invalid Syntax Error on the *break* line, what have I got wrong?

```
while True:
if cont != "no":
    num = (int(input("Type a number. ")))
    num_remainder = num % 2
    if num_remainder == 0:
        print ()
        print (num, " is an even number.")
    else:
        print ()
        print (num, " is an odd number.")
cont= (input("Would you like to continue?")
    continue
else:
    break
```

Thanks

Comment: Your identation is wrong (at least for attached code)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is simpler,

```
while True:
    num = int(input("Type a number. "))
    print ()  # blank line before assert whether is or not a even number
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print (num, " is an even number.")
    else:
        print (num, " is an odd number.")

    if input("Would you like to continue?") == 'no':  # Ohh, you want to break now.
        break
```